# How to append a line at the end of the file using sed

Tags: bash, sed

The following command works fine assuming the test.txt file already exists:

```
sed -i -e '$a\
This line was appended at the end.' test.txt
```

But this command take two lines. I would rather have a single line instead, like so:

```
sed -i -e '$a\ This line was appended at the end.' test.txt
```

But unfortunately it raises an error:

```
sed: 1: "$a\ This line was appended at the end.": extra characters after \ at the end of a command
```

Would it be possible to get this command working as a single line?

Comment: `echo "new line" >> test.txt`

Comment: With GNU sed the `-e` option is not needed and for me `$aAppend this line` or `$a\Append this line` work equally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `$'\n'` which the shell translates to a newline:

```
sed -i -e '$a\'$'\n''This line was appended at the end.' test.txt
```

or

```
sed -i -e $'$a\\\nThis line was appended at the end.'
```